Is $y_t = z_t x_t$ Always IID When $x_t$ is a Stationary Process?
I am exploring the properties of a stochastic process defined by the pointwise product of two other processes. Firts, consider the process $y_t = z_t x_t$, where $x_t$ is an AR(1) process, and $z_t$ is an iid process with mean zero.
Let:
$$
x_t = 0.8 x_{t-1} + u_t,
$$
where $u_t \sim N(0, 1)$ is white noise (iid normal with mean 0 and variance 1).
Let $z_t$ be an iid process such that:
$$
z_t \sim \text{iid}, \quad E(z_t) = 0, \quad \text{Var}(z_t) = \sigma^2_z.
$$
Step-by-Step Analysis

Independence of $y_t$:
Since $z_t$ is iid and independent of $x_t$, and considering that each $x_t$ is generated recursively with the innovation $u_t$, it follows that each $y_t = z_t x_t$ is independent of $y_{t-1} = z_{t-1} x_{t-1}$. To show this, we can compute the autocovariance:
$$
   \text{Cov}(y_t, y_{t-1}) = \text{Cov}(z_t x_t, z_{t-1} x_{t-1}).
   $$
Given the independence of $z_t$ and $z_{t-1}$, we have:
$$
   \text{Cov}(z_t, z_{t-1}) = 0.
   $$
Therefore,
$$
   \text{Cov}(y_t, y_{t-1}) = E[z_t z_{t-1} x_t x_{t-1}] - E[z_t x_t]E[z_{t-1} x_{t-1}].
   $$
Since $E[z_t] = E[z_{t-1}] = 0$, it follows that:
$$
   E[z_t x_t] = E[z_t]E[x_t] = 0, \quad E[z_{t-1} x_{t-1}] = E[z_{t-1}]E[x_{t-1}] = 0.
   $$
Thus,
$$
   \text{Cov}(y_t, y_{t-1}) = E[z_t z_{t-1}] E[x_t x_{t-1}].
   $$
And since $z_t$ and $z_{t-1}$ are independent:
$$
   E[z_t z_{t-1}] = E[z_t]E[z_{t-1}] = 0.
   $$
This implies that:
$$
   \text{Cov}(y_t, y_{t-1}) = 0.
   $$
Hence, $y_t$ and $y_{t-1}$ are uncorrelated, suggesting that $y_t$ is independent over time if this holds for all lags.

Identical Distribution:
Given that $x_t$ follows an AR(1) process and reaches a stationary distribution, each $x_t$ is identically distributed. Since $z_t$ is iid and independent of $x_t$, the product $y_t = z_t x_t$ will also be identically distributed, assuming $x_t$ has the same distribution over time.


Main Question
Is the conclusion that $y_t = z_t x_t$ is iid always true for any stationary process $x_t$, or is it specific to the AR(1) case?
Can we generalize this result to any stationary process $x_t$, not just AR(1)?

Is the sequence $(z_t)$ independent of the sequence $(u_t)$? In any case, if $(X_t)$ is a sequence such that $\operatorname{Cov}(X_t,X_{t-1})=0$ for each $t$, you cannot conclude that $(X_t)$ is independent. Actually, unless the sequence is Gaussian, you cannot even conclude that $X_t$ is independent of $X_{t-1}$.

It's even stronger than what David said because $x_t$ and $x_{t-1}$ are not uncorrelated. In your derivation you skipped over the fact that $E(x_{t}x_{t-1}) \neq 0$ so you can't seperate the z's from the x's in the expectation $E(z_{t} z_{t-1} x_{t} x_{t-1})$.

Yes, $(z_t)$ and $(u_t)$ are independent.Thanks for your comments and pointing out my mistakes. I'll redo my math and get back to you.

Even though your approach wasn't perfect, I'm not sure about your conclusion. It may be correct ? I'm looking forward to a full answer from you or anyone else. Thanks for interesting question.

Actually, I was investigating which properties prevail after the multiplication of the processes. For a moment, I thought that the iid property of $(z_t)$ was transferred to $y_t$, but that is not true. So, perhaps something to investigate is whether $y_t$ is an autoregressive process. If it is not the case, can we at least demonstrate that the process $(y_t)$ is ergodic in the sense of $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n g (y_t) \to E[g(y_1)]$ almost sure ($g$ being a measurable function) ? I will try to reformulate my question in the next few hours.

@user346624 That's an interesting time-series topic that I never even heard of before. I don't even know the name of the sub-field so that you could look at a reference or a text ? Hopefully someone else can say something because, although it's interesting, I doubt that I can help. (I'm not a math person but I like this site for learning).
